# NHibernate: Save Object1 with List<Object2> into database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have problem with my Nhibernate app.
I have class called Rozmiar, and class called Symbol.
Symbol contains List as property.

How can I save it into database using NHibernate?

My code (doesn't working properly):

SYMBOL CLASS:

```
public class Symbol
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nazwa { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Sitodruk { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Rozmiar> Rozmiar { get; set; }

    public Symbol() { }

    public Symbol(string nazwa, List<Rozmiar> lista)
    {
        using (ISession sesja = Program.baza.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = sesja.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Symbol s = new Symbol();
                s.Nazwa = nazwa;
                s.Rozmiar = lista;
                sesja.Save(s);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ROZMIAR CLASS:

```
    public class Rozmiar
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nazwa { get; set; }

        public Rozmiar() { }


        public Rozmiar(string nazwa)
        {
            using (ISession sesja = Program.baza.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = sesja.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Rozmiar r = new Rozmiar();
                    r.Nazwa = nazwa;
                    sesja.Save(r);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

MAP:

```
public class RozmiarMap : ClassMap<Rozmiar>
{
    public RozmiarMap()
    {
        Table("Rozmiar");
        SchemaAction.All();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(X => X.Nazwa).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class SymbolMap : ClassMap<Symbol>
{
    public SymbolMap()
    {
        Table("Symbol");
        SchemaAction.All();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Nazwa).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Rozmiar).KeyColumn("IdRozmiar");
    }
}
```

And method to generate sample objects:

```
public static void Generuj()
        {
            List<Rozmiar> listA = new List<Rozmiar>();
            listA.Add(new Rozmiar("750 mm"));
            listA.Add(new Rozmiar("900 mm"));
            listA.Add(new Rozmiar("1050 mm"));
            listA.Add(new Rozmiar("1200 mm"));

            Symbol a1 = new Symbol("A-1", listA);
            Symbol a2 = new Symbol("A-2", listA);
            Symbol a3 = new Symbol("A-3", listA);
        }
```

In debugging mode, I saw, that listA contains 4 objects, but properties of those objects ale Id = 0 and Nazwa = null :( Maybe there is a main problem...

I also don't know, if my mapping is set properly.

BTW. Connections settings and config are ok, because i have other classes in this code, and it saves properly into database.

Comment: Could you explain me in details your database model? By what I understood, if Symbol has a list of Rozmiar, so table Rozmiar has a FK IdSymbol that references table Symbol, and not Symbol has FK that references Rozmiar as you show in your mapping...

Comment: Thanks for reply, Rafael. My problem was solved by Radim :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of `Rozmiar` with string parameter, you are creating different (`new`) instance of the `Rozmiar`. So while you are adding into the `listA` instance created by

```
new Rozmiar("750 mm")
```

persisted is different object

```
Rozmiar r = new Rozmiar();
```

Also, change your mapping from `List<Rozmiar>` into `IList<Rozmiar>`. See here: [6.1. Persistent Collections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-persistent) the complete list of supported interfaces for collection mapping

Comment: Thank you, Radim. I repaired those two little mistakes, and my code works properly :)

Comment: I have one more question... Why does if I make, for example: 2 lists of Rozmiar, and 10 objects Symbol with list1, and 5 objects with list2 , In database I see only two last Ids of my objects (id = 10 for list1, and id = 5 for list2) ? I think, I must use something like Cascade, but it isn't work

Comment: Well, I am not sure, but you are using Transaction for single operation. I would be (I am) using transaction for a batch of operations. Persist all or nothing. So, I am using DAO with transaction opened and closed for the life time of the (web) request.